# Chrome Dev tools saves local CSS on one line

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I use Chrome Dev Tools synced to my local filesystem to write all of my CSS. Unfortunately, Dev Tools will sometimes output a class all in one line, even if it was declared in several lines

**Declared:**

```
.style {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: red;
}
```

**Outputted:**

```
.style { font-size: 16px;color: red; }
```

Dev Tools didn't behave this way originally for me, but now does. I played around with some settings to no avail.

Comment: Do you want to change the behaviors of how css look? Please provide screenshots too.

Comment: So I would like to have the outputted styles by Chrome all on their own line, rather than on one line. It may seem small, but for this node module I'm building, this is somewhat of a big deal.

Comment: Could be a bug in Chrome. Consider submitting a [bug report](https://crbug.com).